# After notifyItemRangeInserted OR Removed the Position didn't get changed

Tags: android

In this Example, I use `GridLayoutManager`. I click one item, then under it will show some picture.

I add three data in my Adapter's Resource then call `notifyItemRangeInserted(position,3);`
then Under the item(position = 3) i clicked come out three new item and I Log their position. The three new item's position is 4,5,6. But when i click the 7 item, it log it's position as 3. I didn't understand.

Under is Some of my Code. My English is not that good. Please Forgive me.

```
    final RecyclerView recyphoto = new RecyclerView(this);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,3);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (recyphoto.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position)==1){
                return 3;
            }else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    if(infos.get(position).getType()==1){
        final ViewHolderOne holderOne = ((ViewHolderOne)holder);

        if(infos.get(position).isExpand()){
            holderOne.imageArrow.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrowdown));
        }else{
            holderOne.imageArrow.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow));

        }

        TextView tv =  holderOne.textView;
        tv.setText(infos.get(position).getName());
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                List<FileInfo> childs = infos.get(position).getChilds();
                int childSize = 0;

                if(childs!=null){
                    childSize=childs.size();
                }

                LogUtil.e(position +"POS");

                if(!infos.get(position).isExpand()) {

                    if(childs!=null) {
                        infos.addAll(position + 1, childs);
                    }
                    infos.get(position).setExpand(true);

                    notifyItemRangeInserted(position,childSize);

                        if(onScrollToBottomListener!=null)
                            onScrollToBottomListener.onBottom(position,infos.size());
                }else{
                    infos.subList(position + 1 , position + 1+childSize).clear();
                    infos.get(position).setExpand(false);
                    notifyItemRangeRemoved(position,childSize);
                }




            }
        });
    }else if(infos.get(position).getType()==2){
        final ViewHolderTwo holderTwo = ((ViewHolderTwo)holder);
        Glide.with(context).load(infos.get(position).getLocation()).override(200,200).centerCrop().into( holderTwo.imageView);

        holderTwo.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!holderTwo.checkPhoto.isChecked()) {
                    sendDatas.add(infos.get(position));
                    holderTwo.checkPhoto.setChecked(true);
                    holderTwo.checkPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    onSendDataChangeListener.onSendDataChange(sendDatas);
                }else{
                    sendDatas.remove(infos.get(position));
                    holderTwo.checkPhoto.setChecked(false);
                    holderTwo.checkPhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    onSendDataChangeListener.onSendDataChange(sendDatas);
                }
            }
        });

        if(belong(sendDatas,position)){
            holderTwo.checkPhoto.setChecked(true);
            holderTwo.checkPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holderTwo.checkPhoto.setChecked(false);
            holderTwo.checkPhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return infos.size();
}

private class ViewHolderOne extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textView ;
    ImageView imageArrow;

    ViewHolderOne(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageArrow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_arrow);
    }
}

private class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView ;
    CheckBox checkPhoto;

    ViewHolderTwo(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        checkPhoto = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_photo);
    }
}



@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return infos.get(position).getType();
}

private boolean belong(List<FileInfo> sendDatas, int pos) {
    String str = infos.get(pos).getLocation();
    for (int i = 0; i < sendDatas.size(); i++) {
        if (str.equals(sendDatas.get(i).getLocation()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you're setting up your `OnClickListener`.

In `onBindViewHolder()`, you write something like this:

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            LogUtil.e(position +"POS");
            ...
        }
};
```

What is `position` here? It's the value passed to `onBindViewHolder()`, which was `3` before you inserted your items.

To fix the behavior, you should do a live query for the item's position when you click it. I don't have my IDE in front of me, but I believe this will work:

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            LogUtil.e(holder.getAdapterPosition() +"POS");
            ...
        }
};
```

`holder.getAdapterPosition()` will determine the item's position *at the time of the click* instead of at binding.